# Dynamically allocating threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, dynamic, pthreads

I'm creating a little program in C which calculates the faculty of numbers the user enters, until the user enters a negative number. It does this using threads.

I get a segmentation fault when running so I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what exactly.

Here is my code:

```
/* 
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: thomasvanhelden
 *
 * Created on June 15, 2014, 3:17 AM
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

/**
 * Calculates faculty of given number
 *      Can run as a thread
 * @param param The given number
 * @return Doesn't return anything
 */
void *fac(void *param) {
    int* number = (int*) param;
    int faculty = 1;
    int i; // counter

    printf("De faculteit van %i is: ", number);

    for (i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
        faculty *= i;
    }

    printf("%i\n", faculty);
}

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    pthread_t **threads; 
    int getal, numThreads = 0, counter, stop = 0;

    // ask for numbers until user enters negative number
    while (stop == 0) {
        scanf("%i", getal);

        if (getal >= 0) {
            numThreads++;
            threads = realloc(threads, sizeof(pthread_t*) * (numThreads+1));
            threads[numThreads - 1] = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));

            // Create the thread
            if (pthread_create(&threads[numThreads - 1], NULL, fac, &getal)) {
                // something went wrong
                printf("Error creating thread %i!\n", numThreads);
                return 1;
            }

        } else {
            // User entered negative number and wants to stop
            stop = 1;
        }
    }

    // join all the threads
    for (counter = 0; counter < numThreads; counter++) {
        if (pthread_join(threads[counter], NULL)) {
            printf("Something went wrong joining thread %i\n", counter + 1);
        }
    }


    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean "factorial"?  Anyway, there are multiple problems with your code. Even without strict flags enabled, I get the following warnings:

```
fac.c:23:40: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
    printf("De faculteit van %i is: ", number);
                             ~~        ^~~~~~
fac.c:25:19: warning: ordered comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'int *')
    for (i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
                ~ ^  ~~~~~~
fac.c:30:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
fac.c:41:21: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
        scanf("%i", getal);
               ~~   ^~~~~
fac.c:49:32: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'pthread_t **' (aka 'struct _opaque_pthread_t ***') to
      parameter of type 'pthread_t *' (aka 'struct _opaque_pthread_t **'); remove &
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
            if (pthread_create(&threads[numThreads - 1], NULL, fac, &getal)) {
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pthread.h:310:42: note: passing argument to parameter here
int pthread_create(pthread_t * __restrict, const pthread_attr_t * __restrict,
                                         ^
fac.c:63:26: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'pthread_t *' (aka 'struct _opaque_pthread_t **') to
      parameter of type 'pthread_t' (aka 'struct _opaque_pthread_t *'); dereference with *
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        if (pthread_join(threads[counter], NULL)) {
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                         *
/usr/include/pthread.h:333:28: note: passing argument to parameter here
int pthread_join(pthread_t , void **) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(pthread_join);
                           ^
6 warnings generated.
```

As it is, if you run the program under `gdb`, it crashes after you enter a number:

```
...
4

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x00007fff92c1401a in __svfscanf_l ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff92c1401a in __svfscanf_l ()
#1  0x00007fff92c0c0eb in scanf ()
#2  0x0000000100000d72 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbffa18) at fac.c:41
```

Looking at the stack trace with `bt`, we see immediately that it is crashing at line 41 where you call `scanf()`.  And if you look back at the compiler warnings, it's telling you that it expects an `int*` but you're only passing an `int`. This is because `scanf` needs a pointer in order to modify the variable with the user input.

If you fix all the remaining warnings, your code works.

- You need to dereference `number` in the `fac` function when you want its value
- You need to initialise `threads` to `NULL` so `realloc` will work (it is otherwise undefined, presumably non-zero and thus the buffer will never be (re)allocated
- The `pthread_create` and `pthread_join` calls need updating so the value/pointer matches the expected signature

After making the changes above, I can run it as intended:

```
$ ./fac_fixed
3
De faculteit van 3 is: 6
4
De faculteit van 4 is: 24
5
De faculteit van 5 is: 120
6
De faculteit van 6 is: 720
7
De faculteit van 7 is: 5040
8
De faculteit van 8 is: 40320
9
De faculteit van 9 is: 362880
12
De faculteit van 12 is: 479001600
-1
```

As to the structure of the code, I don't see why you want to create an array of threads anyway, as you are only calculating one at a time, sequentially. You only really need at most one worker thread, but since `main` is doing nothing but blocking on a join anyway, it doesn't really need to be in a thread.  But at least it doesn't crash!

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to fix my code! Yes, there is no need to create an array of threads. But I made it as an exercise, so it has no real purpose.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `realloc()` the first time, you should have `threads` set to NULL. As it is, you are passing an uninitalized pointer which is *undefined behaviour*.

1) Initialize it to 0:

```
pthread_t **threads = 0;
```

2) You are also printing the pointers rather than what they point to here:

```
printf("De faculteit van %i is: ", *number);
```

3) scanf() needs `&` as it expects `int *` for `%d`.

```
scanf("%i", &getal);
```